# How to impose correct ordering in nested query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, one of items, and one of users who have flagged the items. Here is an example:

```
items:                              flags:

item_id | item_name | owner_id      item_id | flagged_by
------------------------------      --------------------
1       | foo       | 1             1       | 2
2       | bar       | 2             2       | 4
3       | baz       | 2             2       | 7
                                    2       | 7
```

I want to select the information from the item table about all the items that are in the flag table, ordered by the number of flags. So for the above example, my desired output would be

```
item_id | item_name | owner_id
------------------------------
2       | bar       | 2
1       | foo       | 1
```

The query I have right now is `select * from items where id in (select item_id from flags group by item_id order by count(*) desc);`

I know that the inner query works correctly (returns all the IDs in the correct order) but when I run the overall query, I just get the items in order of item id. How do I fix my query?

Comment: This looks similar to a question I recently asked.  See [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131150/mysql-which-value-has-maximum-count[/link].  hth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are ordering the subquery only currently, which doesn't have an effect on the order of the outer query.  If you join the tables rather than using a subquery, you should be able to apply an order to the whole query:

```
  select i.*
    from items i
    join flags f on i.item_id = f.item_id
group by i.item_id
order by count(f.item_id) desc
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f141b/2